# Using sendBroadcast for update android widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent

I am creating a appwidget which needs to update when some changing in app's database.
What I do:
1. Create working widget
2. Override onReceive method:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CHANGED = " utimetable.DATABASE_CHANGED";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(DATABASE_CHANGED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) 
    {
        AppWidgetManager gm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] ids = gm.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, widget_provider.class));
        this.onUpdate(context, gm, ids);            
    }
    else 
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

1. In AndroidManifest:

   ```
       <receiver android:name=".widget_provider" android:label="@string/widget_today_name">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
           <action android:name="utimetable.DATABASE_CHANGED" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
       </intent-filter>
       <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_row" />
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Add Broadcast sending into all DB changing functions:

   ```
   public static void sendUpdateIntent(Context context) 
   {
       Intent i = new Intent(context, widget_provider.class);
       i.setAction(widget_provider.DATABASE_CHANGED);
       context.sendBroadcast(i);
   }
   ```

---

But widget still not updated when I make changes in DB.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just guessing looking at your code, but that space after the first " looks wrong

```
.... DATABASE_CHANGED = " utimetable.DATABASE_CHANGED";
```

Comment: seems right...
however one more thing, maybe i'm mixing with Intents made for Activities, but once you write 'new Intent(context, widget_provider.class);' you will send the intent only to widget_provider class... try to remove it and use: new Intent(widget_provider.DATABASE_CHANGED);

Comment: good point ... I didn't read any further after that first mistake :-).  there is also another way, don't send an intent, instead just update the remoteviews